# Rollback Whatsapp Web update?

Tags: whatsapp

[image]

A few days ago this message popped up in my Whatsapp web (in Firefox browser) and I clicked on it to update my Whatsapp web.

Now I wish to rollback the update to the previous version. Anybody know how I can do this? I guess the update must have loaded some new script or code in my PC, can I just delete those scripts/codes?

FYI, the PC runs on Win XP SP3 and I'm using Firefox 52.9.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete the scripts erasing all site data and the service worker, but you can't return to a previos WhatsApp Web version. If this version is doing you some problem, you must only hope that they changed and fixed the code and, once cleared the scripts, it'll work correctly.